# Is CiviVolunteer a live project or is it dead?

Tags: civivolunteer

I see that is not update and not sure it works with the last version of CiviCRM, do you think is a dead project? is there an alternative?

Comment: You may be able to do a lot of what you need for volunteer management with custom Activity Types

Comment: Is it possible with custom activity type to manage opportunities?

Answer (score 2):

[CiviVolunteer](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer) has limitations I've found that unfortunately do not make it that user-friendly. My use has been with Wordpress, and there are conflicts with it on the front-end. I would consider it almost dead. The issue queue is long and it doesn't appear to being actively developed.

The movement is towards the [Resources Management extension](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.resource). Here's the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/resource/en/latest/). It's more flexible, uses more of CiviCRM's core infrastructure and accounts for non-human resources.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it is very interesting to better understand Rsource Management. I'm not so sure it replace CiviVolunteer and I'm not sure how to install it :)

Comment: (it give me error on both kit and resource event)

Answer (score 0):

gave me several errors and crashes in the execution of the forms. Unusable